# How to create a "on/off" graphs with HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

I've read [the documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs) quite a few times, but I just can't seem to find a way to make a graph like this. Perhaps it's because I don't know what it's called, so I'm not even sure what to look for. Let me try to explain what I'm trying to do.

Normally if you have a series of points like this:

```
3 May, 5:00 PM ---> 0
3 May, 5:20 PM ---> 3
4 May, 5:00 PM ---> 0
4 May, 5:20 PM ---> 3
```

If you make a standard LINE GRAPH, high charts will plot the values INCREASE between the two.  So I end up with this:

[image]

But the problem is, the values being shown are actually values changing at a point in time. In other words, what I want is this:

[image]

And even more importantly, it seems the spacing between time isn't correct. You'll notice that it creates a perfect zigzag, even though the times between the first and second point is 20 minutes (5PM to 5:20 PM), and the second point and 3rd point is 23 hours and 40 minutes (3 May 5:20 PM and 4 May 5PM). So what I really want is this:

[image]

1. Any idea what a graph like this is called?
2. Any idea how to make it using HighCharts?

**UPDATE**

The only solution I can think of right now, is to fake points between the real points. so for example if the value is 0 at 5PM and turns to 3 at 5:20 PM, then I will add 19 points in between these two. So at 5:01 I will make it 0, and 5:02 I will also make it 0, and 5:03 etc. Until 5:19. But even this method will result in a SLIGHTLY skewed line going up from 5:19 to 5:20. Which is what I'm actually trying to avoid.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

The "step : left" solution has definitely solved half of my problem, but for some reason I still have this:

[image]

You should now see that even though I have steps, they are not quite making the expected spacing. For 17:13 on 5 May, I expect the graph to be closer to the 6 May mark, than to the 5 May mark.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE 3**

I created a jFiddle for my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/coderama/ubz7m0Lh/4/

**UPDATE 4**

Based on wergeld's input, it seems using "ordinal" on the x axis is the way to go --> http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal

But it produces a pretty weird graph: https://jsfiddle.net/coderama/6tz8h53x/1/

I'll keep looking, but at least it feels like there's progress being made!

Comment: What I think you want is a `step` chart. See here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.step. As for your point separation it looks like you have some option ticked to trim out null points. Do you have sample code to show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`step`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.step) option. You can set up something like:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Step line types, with null values in the series'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 86400000
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 3, 17, 00), 0],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 3, 20, 00), 3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 4, 17, 00), 0],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 5, 18, 00), 3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 5, 19, 00), 0],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 6, 20, 00), 3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 7, 17, 00), 0]
      ],
      step: 'left'
    }]
  });
});
```

The step parameter tells highcharts how to go from your given point to the next point.

Comment: This works great! Thanks. But for some reason I still get stuck with the times not quite matching up. Will update my question to show what I mean.

Comment: @coderama, I see your update. If possible can you put a jsFiddle with your current config and representative data? There are several things can cause the xAxis to appear offset from the data points themselves.

Comment: @coderama, Ah, have a look at `xAxis.ordinal` (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal). Set it to false to see your data "for real". (https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/ubz7m0Lh/6/)

Comment: The descriptions seems to describe my problem exactly, but the graph looks really weird. Did you try to tweak it on jfiddle? I'll keep looking, but thanks for the nudge in the right direction!! :)

Comment: I made a new jFiddle using the change you recommended here: https://jsfiddle.net/coderama/6tz8h53x/1/

Comment: Yea, you might need to change up what your initial scale is and your tick intervals.

Comment: Looks like your "off" interval is only 7 minutes so you "on" sections are much, much larger (essentially 24 hours). Is this how your data always looks?

Comment: The graph is of a user setting the fan speed from 0, to 1, to 2, to 3. Its unlikely the user will change the fan speed very quickly, but it seems it happens once or twice a day, and it happens 10 minutes apart. At least in this example. Does that help?

Comment: p.s. I tried setting the tick interval to 1 and it still shows the graph looking weird.

Comment: If that is the nature of your data...then yes, the chart might look odd. Again, changing your initial zoom state may let it look better.

Comment: A tickInterval of 1 on a datetime xAxis is 1 ms...yes, that would look odd. Try changing to 12 hours in ms or maybe 1 day.

Comment: Hmmm. Still exact same result. Will have to keep digging! But thank you so much!

Comment: Oh my gosh, i think i get it. It looks weird, but its not wrong! :-) Its because there is such a tiny space between the two points! Let me try a few more examples... Thanks!!

Comment: The tickInterval changes will just modify your xAxis label text. Look at your initial zoom state for better views.